# How to connect MS SQL Server DB to an Oracle Cloud DB

Tags: sql-server, ssh, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm facing a challenge here where I need to bring some data from an Oracle cloud DB (it's outside our intranet) into an MSSQL DB.
I found some pointers where I can, via an SSH tunnel config in SQL Developer, connect to this Oracle cloud DB, but I've never done this before. Any experience out there with such a setup? Or any other kind of way to achieve this?

Hope you can help, thanks

Comment: Does the Oracle DB have a public ip? If not, is there a fastconnect connection or an ipsec tunnel in place to connect your on-prem network to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure?

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to connect Oracle Cloud DB to a MSSQL DB, please refer to https://www.sqlshack.com/link-sql-server-oracle-database/ as it has the details to configure any external DB with Oracle DB.